# Как осуществляется обработка ошибок в mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Как в процедурном php при добавлении информации в БД обрабатываются ошибки? В интернете много противоречивой информации, я так и не понял, как это сделать правильно.

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (login, email, password, datetime) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $sql);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss', $login, $email, $password, $datetime);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Библиотека mysqli - своеобразный мостик между процедурным и объектно-ориентированным стилем программирования. Поэтому она поддерживает два подхода обработки ошибок: процедурный и через исключения.

Первый, процедурный подход - вы проверяете результат выполнения каждой функции и если возвращается `false`, получаете сообщение при помощи функции `mysqli_error()`

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "...", "test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Ошибка установки соединения" . mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (login, email, password, datetime) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $sql);
if(!$stmt) {
  echo "Ошибка подготовки запроса: " . mysqli_error($db);
  exit();
}
if(!mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss', $login, $email, $password, $datetime)) {
  echo "Ошибка связывания параметров: " . mysqli_error($db);
  exit();
}
if(!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
  echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: " . mysqli_error($db);
  exit();
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($db);
```

Разумеется это не очень удобно, особенно, в объектно-ориентированном коде, поэтому mysqli позволяет переключиться в режим генерации исключений (их несколько типов, в режиме отладки наиболее удобно использовать `MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL`). Задать режим можно при помощи функции `mysqli_report()`

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL); 

try {
  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "...", "test");

  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (login, email, password, datetime) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $sql);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss', $login, $email, $password, $datetime);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  mysqli_close($db);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Ошибки перехватываются при помощи стандартного механизма исключений. Не смотря на то, что вы выбрали процедурный стиль, вы можете воспользоваться перехватом исключений, который чаще применяется в объектно-ориентированном коде.

Comment: А mysqli_report - перед каждым обращением к бд устанавливать, или в начале всего скрипта?

Comment: @Vlad, достаточно в начале всего скрипта